# unable to send more than one file through socket in android

Tags: java, android, sockets, io

I am trying to record audio into a file in the server side which is an android device and send it to client, another android device when the record is done. It works fine for the first time, but when I record again, my second record is not received by the client. Here is my code

SERVER THREAD:

```
public class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            if (SERVERIP != null) {
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                while (true) {
                    client = serverSocket.accept();
                    OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
                    while(true){
                        //record status is true 
                        //when record is done
                        if(record_status){
                            try {
                                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(mFileName)));
                                BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
                                copyFile(bis, bout);
                                bout.flush();
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            record_status = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

CLIENT THREAD:

```
    public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVERIP);
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
            connected = true;
            while (connected) {
                try {
                    dis = socket.getInputStream();
                    while(true){
                        if(dis.available()>0){
                        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(mFileName)));
                        copyFile(socket.getInputStream(), bos);
                        bos.flush();
                        //file has been received
                        //start playing the audio
                        startPlaying();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            connected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

method copyFile:

```
    public static boolean copyFile(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream out) {
    byte buf[] = new byte[4092];
    int len;
    try {
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buf)) != -1) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);

        }
        out.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This really should be a comment, however i don't have  the rep yet. But it seems to me that on the server side you have record_status set to true on first iteration of while loop once that stream is sent to client then record_status is set false and never actually set to true again inside the while loop. As a result the code inside the if statement is never executed again. So where does record_status get set to true again? check the logcat on server side device to see if anything is actually put into bitstream for the second recording if not this is your problem

Comment: record_status is set true every time I stop recording, private void stopRecording() {
  mRecorder.stop();
  mRecorder.release();
  record_status = true;
 }

Comment: where is that exactly? its not in any of the posted code? how are you executing the ServerThread (is it in the same thread which calls stopRecording)? did you check logcat as suggested to see the if Your server is actually sending any data out for the second recording? as I doubt it is

Comment: Here is the [code](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html) I'm using for recording and playing, the server records, and when recording stops, stopRecording() method is called where record_status is set true and it sends the file to client and client plays the received file.

Comment: @kader LogCat do you know what this is? is the second file being sent? ... what you say is happening, clearly is not, or it would work! the code you linked doesn't even include a record_status variable and is meant to be executed on a single machine in a single thread. How do you call your ServerThread? without seeing your code, or a logcat output i can't help you and im sure as hell not going to write your app for you

Comment: post some logcat results, or your actual code (not google's that your attempting to modify)